# Why is "dingbat" used to refer to characters like "☺"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, typography

Why is *dingbat* used to refer to characters such as "☺"?

(See for instance those at the [Mozilla Web Developer FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ).)

Doesn't *dingbat* mean a stupid person or something?

Comment: There is a correlation between the two if you think about it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [dingbat](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dingbat) is "an ornamental piece of type for borders, separators, decorations, etc." as well as a silly person.  The fonts are called [dingbat fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat) because they contain such characters.

The word's [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dingbat&searchmode=none) leads me to believe that it is a generic word, akin to widget, doohickey, and thingamajig.

Answer (score 5):

Dingbat is *a typographical device other than a letter or numeral (such as an asterisk), used to signal divisions in text or to replace letters in a euphemistically presented vulgar word*.

> ORIGIN mid 19th cent. (in early use applied to various vaguely
>   specified objects): origin uncertain; perhaps based on obsolete ding
>   [to beat, deal heavy blows.]

I also think that the correlation with its other sense *(a stupid or eccentric person)* is rather apparent.